# Decode to raw and reencode to mp3

Tags: lame, re-encoding

I have the following mp3 file

http://peterspace.de/speek.wav now I call this script

```
lame -b 128 --resample 44 speek.wav speek_resampled.mp3
lame --mp3input --resample 44 --decode -t speek_resampled.mp3
lame -r -s 44 speek_resampled.wav speek.new.mp3
```

but now the speek.new.mp3 plays to fast.. it seems that the raw pcm is not 44khz, but 22khz because

```
lame -r -s 22 speek_resampled.wav speek.new.mp3
```

gets a result witrh the right speed. Why isn't the raw format 44khz? even when i define "--resample 44" at decoding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was that speek.wav is stereo, and in raw format this information was lost